# Set TextWrapping to Paragraphin WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

How is it possible to wrap a text in an Paragraph element? Actually there is no property in Paragraph or Run element?

Comment: Set Wrap text property in a RichTextBox which is parent to Paragraph

Comment: I've set the wrap property in a RichTextBox, but it has no function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the text in either a RichEditBox or a RichTextBlock, it will wrap by default, if the container constrains the width of the UI Element.

For example, this code below works fine.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <RichEditBox x:Name="reb"/>
    <RichTextBlock x:Name="rtb" Grid.Column="1">
        <Paragraph>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse 
            bibendum nibh quis leo ultrices condimentum. Vestibulum dolor mi, lacinia
            non rutrum ac, mollis quis odio. Nulla tristique massa id magna tincidunt
            faucibus. Duis lacinia nunc in arcu eleifend semper. Etiam sed enim leo.
            Proin eu mi ut nulla congue tempus nec at velit. Ut ut nisi lectus. In sit
            amet dui a sem elementum dictum. Mauris eget mi sit amet arcu euismod
            elementum. In pretium cursus arcu, nec ultricies leo ultrices ac. Sed
            urna erat, posuere vel molestie sed, suscipit in nunc. Suspendisse potenti.
            Phasellus fringilla laoreet augue, vel tincidunt eros feugiat vel. Fusce 
            vel scelerisque dui. Praesent vel augue quis ligula bibendum vulputate vel vitae nisl.
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Using the code found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR227548) to load a local RTF document into the RichEditBox, the text wraps as expected. The text also wraps for a RichTextBlock by default.

Paragraphs can't be individually toggled to wrap/no wrap. It's the container that controls it. On the RichTextBlock for example, it's the TextWrapping property.